# google drive api php

Tags: google-drive-api

do you know how can i make to create a directory in Google Drive with php. the php file is a webservice and the user hasn't interaction with the file, this php file is call by CRM Application (Zoho CRM WebHooks).

Is it possible to have a token OAuth for longtime as many aanother application ?

thanks

Comment: i find https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Answer (score 2):

A Google Drive folder is a file which has a `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` mime type. Insert a new file with this mime type. You need to ask for a refresh token, PHP library automatically asks new tokens. It's greatly documented on https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline